# Firewalld instead of iptables on XenServer 7

Tags: iptables, xenserver, firewalld

I'm a huge fan of CentOSs firewalld. Mostly because it was introduced when I began working with linux servers. I've also tried to understand iptables but it was nothing more than sscratching the surface. Now I wish to implement some firewall rules onto my XenServer. For this, I wish to disable iptables, install and enable firewalld. Unfortunately I'm unable to install firewalld because of the following error:

```
Error: libselinux conflicts with systemd-219-19.el7_2.7.xs7.1.x86_64
```

I could install with yum install firewalld --skip-broken but I'm affraid it would break the server in some form. Can you tell me how will I be able to install firewalld properly? Even despite the fact that installing with yum is highly non-recommended.

Thanks in advance!

Bert

Comment: `firewald` is using `netfilter`/`iptables` internally. At least until it will be replaced with `nftables`.

Comment: You didn't say anything new.

Comment: Make sure you don't have conflicting repositories. sounds like you have an old version of firewalld or of systemd in yum somewhere..

Comment: Could you show whole error when install `firewalld`?